# ¿Cómo puedo usar un public static String dentro de los parametros de un método?

Tags: java, string, netbeans

Tengo declarados Strings como públicos y estáticos al principio de todo mi código, junto a un array fuera del *main*, pero quiero usar esas declaraciones dentro de un método. El problema es que tengo que declarar nuevamente los Strings dentro de los parámetros del método que quiero usar.

```
public class CajeroAutomatico {
     static Scanner s;   //Scanner de lectura de datos
     public static int cnt=0;   //contador de cuentas
     public static String[][] cuentas = new String[10][]; //Array para almacenar cuentas
     public static String usuario;
     public static String contra; [...]}
```

Aquí regirstro las cuentas que solicita el programa:

```
     System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo usuario: ");
     usuario = s.next();
     System.out.println("Ingrese la contraseña: ");
     contra = s.nextLine();
     crearCuenta(usuario, contra);   //Envia los nuevos datos al metodo crearCuenta();
```

Éste es un método llamado inicializar, que registra cuentas predeterminadas sólo de prueba:

```
public static void inicializar(){
    s=new Scanner(System.in);
    crearCuenta("1235", "abdc");
    crearCuenta("4567", "efgh");
}
```

Y finalmente, éste es mi método crearCuenta();

```
public static void crearCuenta(String usuario, String contra){
    cnt++;
    cuentas[cnt][0] = "" + (cnt+1);
    cuentas[cnt][1] = usuario;
    cuentas[cnt][2] = contra;
}
```

Cuando mando datos para crear una nueva cuenta, sí me reconoce las Strings globales que tengo, pero en *inicializar();* y *crearCuenta();* me reconoce y envía datos de los parámetros que me pide declarar el método *crearCuenta();*.

El problema está en que, ya que tengo que declarar parámetros de entrada en el método *crearCuenta();* no puedo usar los Strings globales declarados al principio. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que en vez de declarar nuevos parámetros use los Strings globales como los parámetros del método.

Comment: Pon la clase completa, no por trozos. No entiendo cuál es el problema. No entiendo por qué pasas parámetros a `crearCuenta()`  con datos así:  `crearCuenta("1235", "abdc");` cuando el método no admite parámetros. Luego, dentro del método, no se sabe de dónde sale `cnt`, etc...

Comment: @A.Cedano cierto, no copié algunos datos, y la clase que estoy usando es demasiado extensa. Ya corregí los parámetros de `crearCuenta();`.

Comment: Pero ¿el error cuál es en sí? Agréga el mensaje de error a la pregunta.

Comment: Listo amigo, ya lo añadí.

Comment: ¿Cómo que no los puedes usar? ¿Por qué no? ¿Qué error da si intentas usarlos?

Comment: Porque me pide declarar parámetros. Y no sé cómo usar los parámetros que declaré el principio. (Soy bastante novato en Java).

Comment: No se entiende el problema. Si pones el mensaje de error podremos ayudarte mejor. Yo no veo exactamente dónde está la dificultad. Te propongo que aísles el problema, creando una clase sencilla de prueba, así puedes poner todo el contexto en la pregunta y decirnos: *me da tal error en tal parte cuando intento hacer tal cosa*.

Comment: Por ejemplo, esto que preguntas es un error de enfoque: *¿Cómo puedo hacer para que en vez de declarar nuevos parámetros use los Strings globales **como los parámetros del método** ...?.*  Si estás **en la misma clase**, no necesitas pasar en parámetro los miembros que declaraste en la cabecera de la clase, solamente usarlos, porque tienes acceso a ellos desde toda la clase y por tanto desde cualquier método de la misma.

Comment: Es que, sí estoy dentro de la misma clase, pero en donde tengo que enviar los datos de usuario y contraseña debo hacerlo enviando los parámetros (al enviarlos, usa los Strings) pero el método me pide declarar nuevos parámetros o me sale un error de argumentos. Es ahí donde no sé cómo usar los Strings en vez de los parámetros que me solicita el método.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas, el principal es que no estás indicando el tamaño de las columnas de tu array.

Luego en la lógica de `crearCuenta()` no es correcta.

Mira un ejemplo que debería funcionar.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{
     public static int cnt=0;
     public static String[][] cuentas = new String[10][3]; //Array para almacenar cuentas
     public static String usuario;
     public static String contra; 

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String mUsuario="Usuario3";
        String mContra="contra3";
        inicializar();
        crearCuenta(mUsuario, mContra);   //Envia los nuevos datos al metodo crearCuenta();

        mUsuario="Usuario4";
        mContra="contra4";
        crearCuenta(mUsuario, mContra);

        /*Prueba del array*/
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(cuentas).replace("], ", "]\n"));

    }

    public static void inicializar(){
        crearCuenta("1235", "abdc");
        crearCuenta("4567", "efgh");
    }

    public static void crearCuenta(String usuario, String contra){
        cuentas[cnt][0] = ""+(cnt+1);
        cuentas[cnt][1] = usuario;
        cuentas[cnt][2] = contra;
        /*OJO a esto, incrementar luego de agregar*/
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
[

    [1, 1235, abdc]
    [2, 4567, efgh]
    [3, Usuario3, contra3]
    [4, Usuario4, contra4]
    [null, null, null]
    [null, null, null]
    [null, null, null]
    [null, null, null]
    [null, null, null]
    [null, null, null]

]
```

### Demo

Ver en **<kbd>[Rextester](https://rextester.com/UENL25457)</kbd>**

Comment: Entonces, ¿puedo usar parámetros con nombre distinto a los que están declarados dentro del método?, si es así, ¡me salvaste de una!

Comment: @OscarAnibal pueden ser distintos o iguales. Yo usé instintivamente `mUser` y `mContra` porque es la convención de nombre que suelo usar. Si usas `user` y `contra` funcionará igual. El problema principal estaba en que no estabas indicando cuántas columnas iba a tener `cuenta`